# Senior colleague does not delegate and gets passive aggressive/resentful when I don't pick up the task myself, how do I deal with this?

Tags: delegation, passive-aggressiveness

The senior colleague asked if one of us juniors could substitute for them in a task. On this date, nobody was available, so nobody came forward with this question. One day later, this senior colleague came to me and complained that when they asked this kind of question, the juniors were expected to come forward to solve it. This looks selective and unfair because we take up tasks, but any, even the most minor tasks, cause resentment and are used to guilt trip us. How can I professionally deal with this behaviour? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is he your team lead ?

Comment: Is this a common occurrence? Is it possible to talk among yourselves and if no one is available communicate it so the senior knows?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 No, one year of seniority, but next year will get the team lead.

Comment: @mattfreake It has been happening more often lately. We can talk among ourselves, but this does not change their behaviour. Any feedback to the senior colleague has not been taken up at all.

Comment: Im not quite sure about what you mean by "This looks selective and unfair because we take up tasks, but any, even the most minor tasks, cause resentment and are used to guilt trip us", does it mean that even if you miss a minor task he berrates you ?

Comment: @Or4ng3h4t I understand. I have not clearly explained this. When we miss or do not take up any minor task, we get berated as if we never take up any tasks, which is not the case.

Comment: So what happens if the senior asks you to do something and you (collectively) reply you can't because you're already doing some other important task?

Comment: Are you using a task management/ticketing system? If so he shouldn't have to ask; either the team leader will have the authority to assign, or you should already be picking up the highest-ranked task that you are capable of handling and the team leader sets the priorities....

Comment: @mattfreake Then we get to hear how non-supportive we are in the team.

Comment: @keshlam Unfortunately not. This is happening in an academic setting within a University, so the organizational level is not up to par with a company.

Comment: Even in academia you should be using task management and a source control system. They're helpful even for solo projects. I presume you are teaching these practices to students; time to start eating your own dogfood. Without task management there is going to be tension over priorities. Though saying "one of you needs to do it" and not closing the loop to confirm that someone has accepted it does not entitle him to complain that nobody did. Consensus on priorities and target dates  is essential, and without that nothing is actually handed off untill it is accepted by someone.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @keshlam's comment; this is up to your team lead to decide. Either they think the work you are already working on takes precedence, or they think the work the senior wants to delegate is more important. If it's the former then you should ask your team lead to clarify this with the senior (and to cut-out the "non supportive" nonsense). If it's the latter then you need to pick up the senior's work but make it clear what is being delayed and why to your team lead.

A ticketing system would make this clearer, but even without one you need to have a defined set of priorities you can all work to.

Comment: And even in academia, you _must_ have a team lead, or at least team triage meetings and agreement on what gets committed to the shared code, or you really do not have a functional team. In the latter case, if you can't click your colleague off the team, or isolate then in a sandbox until/unless their contribution has been reviewed and approved, the only choices I see are to accept their weaknesses and compensate for them, or to get yourself off that project and onto one that isn't using"academic" as a synonym for "sloppy." Set an example for your students.

Comment: Remember that it is possible to "fire" a collaborator by team consensus, even when you are all peers and volunteers. Talk to your department head about how to do so with minimal conflict.